# Why does this recursion function only set once?

Tags: java, recursion

I know that recursion keeps being executed till it meets the base case.

However, why does this recursion function only set head's child once?

When the head becomes null, it returns the node and sets the head's either left child or right child as node.

I get this concept, but why doesn't this recursion function sets all the left children or right children as nodes even though it's recursion function?

One more question, this recursion stops when the head is null, but why doesn't this recursion set null's child as node? this recursion sets previous of null's head's child as node. Why is it?

```
public Node<Integer> insert(Node<Integer> head, Node<Integer> node){
    if(head == null){
        return node;
    }

    if(head.getData() >= node.getData()){
        head.setLeftChild(insert(head.getLeftChild(), node));
    } else {
        head.setRightChild(insert(head.getRightChild(), node));
    }

    return head;
}
```

Comment: How does `null` have a head or children at all?

Comment: yup I get it Matt. So in a recursion function, if we wanna execute something and if it cannot be executed, we go on to the stack's next and execute that? I just wanted to verify my assumption.

Comment: Read your source  code carefully, the reason is fairly obvious, if you still can't see it, "analyze" the `if` block, the problem is in there

Comment: @Dummy it's not obvious to me. Why don't you post a full answer?

Comment: I want you to figure out yourself, but if you insist, here it is, you never set `head` to anything when the null check is true, so it is always `null` no matter what

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What we have here is a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) insertion function.

The function takes two nodes as parameters: `head` being the root of the binary tree, and `node` is the new node you are inserting into it.

The new `node` will be inserted in such a way that a [depth-first in-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#In-order_2) of the tree will yield an ascending sequence of integers.

> why does this recursion function only set head's child once?

It sets all tree nodes along the path from root node to inserted node's position on the way out of recursion. Only the first assignment is meaningful though, because all others just set the same node without change.

> why doesn't this recursion function sets all the left children or right children as nodes even though it's recursion function?

Each call of the function in this recursion sets left, right or no child. If you follow the execution carefully, you will see at which position in the tree which child is set.

> why doesn't this recursion set null's child as node?

The [recursion exit condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_termination) prevents any operations on a `head` if it's value is `null` - it returns the `node` that you want to insert instead to the previous recursion call where the actual insertion takes place.

Answer (score 1):

`insert` returns in most cases `head`. Whenever it returns `head`, `head.setLeftChild(insert(head.getLeftChild(), node))` results in `head.setLeftChild(head.getLeftChild())` and `head.setRightChild(insert(head.getRightChild(), node))` results in `head.setRightChild(head.getRightChild())`. i.e. in most cases, the calls to `setLeftChild` and `setRightChild` don't change the left/right child of the current `head` `Node`.

Only when `insert(head.getLeftChild(), node)` or `insert(head.getRightChild(), node))` is passed a `null` value (i.e. when `head.getLeftChild()` or `head.getRightChild()` are `null`), the recursive call returns the new `Node`, `node`, which causes `head.setLeftChild(insert(head.getLeftChild(), node))` to result in `head.setLeftChild(node)` and `head.setRightChild(insert(head.getRightChild(), node))` to result in `head.setRightChild(node)`.